# null values sent by jQuery.ajax() are bound to "null" fields in the model

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I want my model's part to be accessible to my page's JavaScript, so I include the following script tag into the model:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var filter = @Html.Raw(@Json.Encode(Model.Filter));
</script>
```

The `filter` object is a filter for the subsequent queries, which are done via AJAX:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function DownloadData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetData")',
        type: "POST",
        data: filter,
        success: function (data) {
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

It all works OK, but for one part: the `filter`'s string properties are not `null`, but `"null"`. I don't touch the `filter` variable in my JavaScript yet

Model:

```
public class SellOffersFilter
{
    public int MinAge { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult SellOffersGetPage(SellOffersFilter filter)
{
    //here both filter.Country and filter.City are equal to "null"
}
```

The POST form looks like `MinAge=0&Country=null&City=null`, and JavaScript debugger shows that `filter.Country` is equal to `null`, not the `"null"` string.

Is there a way to force jQuery not to pack the filter's fields into the POST request, if they are `null`? Or another easy way to pass `null` values through `jQuery.ajax()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't figure out the answer, so I had to manually replace null values with empty strings on the server.

Answer (score 1):

This is most definitely something you should do on your server, not on the client.

Making the client not use "null" by mistake doesn't mean the client can't do a request with null values.

The whole AJAX concept falls short of proper validation, where people are pushing validation to the client-side level. **This is wrong.** It means there will be more hidden server bugs in the future (for all kinds of hackers to exploit).

Comment: I don't understand how this is relevant to my question. I'm not talking about validation at all. All I want is that null values are not turned into "null" strings on the request.

Comment: A request is a string. A null value can be represented in different ways, but equal to none. It could mean "null", "" (empty) as well as %00 (null character).

Comment: Thank you for your time, but this doesn't answer my question at all

Comment: Zruty - It answers your question well. It's just you that don't want to bother putting 1+1...